# XeLaTeX: global colors setting being blocked by a tikz command after a recent update

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, color

After a recent update to my TeX Live 2022 distribution, there seems to be something wrong with the colors with `xelatex`. Consider the following example (compiling with XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\color{red}
\tikz \draw (0,0)--(0,1);
Text

\end{document}
```

The text after the `\tikz` should be red, but now I'm getting:

[image]

What is going on here?

Comment: the new xdvipdfmx has support for color stacks and we modified graphics-def/xetex.def to use them, but something seems wrong somewhere, for now you can use the texlive 2021 xetex.def, we'll look.....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle According to you , the `xetex.def` came with the MacTeX 2022 package should be fine. It seems like something I installed this week broke the correct behavior -- I only encountered this problem after the most recent update.

Comment: yes we just pushed out a new xetex.def as it was waiting for the xdvipdfmx to be in for a couple of releases so it could be assumed to be available.  Not sure yet if it is the macro code or xdvipdfmx which is not working as expected

Comment: See discussion at https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/60905809#60905809

Comment: `xdvipdfmx` isn't quite working as expected so we have reverted the change to xetex.def to use its new color stacks, already submited to ctan, may take some days to reach tex disributions.  Thanks for the clear test file.